# create a application role using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I have created app registration in azure aad. I want to add a app role using Microsoft Graph API programmatic.

Comment: May be this link will help : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/multitenant-identity/app-roles#roles-using-azure-ad-security-groups

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is no [Microsoft Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/overview) to do that. If Azure AD graph is acceptable, you use the following rest API to do that.

```
PATCH https://graph.windows.net/{tenantId}/directoryObjects/{objectId}/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Application?api-version=1.6
```

**Note**: **objectId** not **applicationId**, we could get it from Azure portal.

The following is the test body

```
appRoles": [
    {
      "allowedMemberTypes": [
        "User"
      ],
      "displayName": "SurveyAdmin",
      "id": "c20e145e-5459-4a6c-a074-b942bbd4cfe1",
      "isEnabled": true,
      "description": "Administrators can manage the Surveys in their tenant",
      "value": "SurveyAdmin"
    }
  ]
```

**Test result:**

[image]

We also could check it in the application manifest from Azure portal.

[image]

Comment: I tried the above steps but its removes the existing roles from from the application manifest file. Could you please tell me how can i solve it..

Comment: You could add the approles  you wanted in the test body. It will override the current approles

Comment: Thanks for your help @Tom Sun.

Comment: Given the obsoletion of Azure AD Graph API, Microsoft Graph API beta has app role management. For example: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/api-reference/beta/api/approleassignment_get.md

Comment: 404 on link above @JariTurkia

Comment: Updated link: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/api-reference/beta/api/approleassignment-get.md

Answer (score 1):

According to my experience, I added appRoles with the help of MicrosoftGraphAPI. You can use this:

```
    respond = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/{apps-Object-ID}"
    request_body = json.dumps({
    "appRoles": [           {
                     "allowedMemberTypes": ['User'],
                     'description': 'access',
                     'displayName': 'access',
                     'id': "XXXX-XXXX-XXX",
                     "isEnabled": "true",
                     "value": "null",
                     "origin": "Application"
                 }
             ]
    })
    
    response = requests.patch(respond, headers, request_body)
```

And don't forget to import json and requests